# How to prevent a wash sale from ESPP share purchases and RSU vesting

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options, wash-sale, espp

Earlier this year I exercised (and held) ISOs my company offered. At the time, the FMV was fairly high but has since dropped. I am looking at selling my previously exercised shares and repurchasing them more than 30 days later. Here is an example (assuming a constant $20.00 share price in November & December):

- Jan 15th: Exercise 1000 XYZ for $1/share with an FMV of $40/share
- Nov 15th: Sell 1000 XYZ for $20/share
- Dec 20th: Exercise 2000 XYZ for $1/share with an FMV of $20/share

This should result in a disqualifying disposition and I would owe regular income tax on $19,000 (1000 x ($20 - $1)); however, my ISO spread hasn't increased so my tax burden may not change by much. The upside is a bit of cash in my pocket and more shares purchased for the same tax obligation.

Unfortunately, I have two other events coming up that complicate this: ESPP share purchases and RSU vesting. If we reexamine the example with those two events added in:

- Jan 15th: Exercise 1000 XYZ for $1/share with an FMV of $40/share
- Nov 15th: Sell 1000 XYZ for $20/share
- Nov 30th: Vest 50 RSUs (FMV $20/share)
- Nov 30th: Purchase 950 XYZ for $18/share (10% discount)
- Dec 20th: Exercise 2000 XYZ for $1/share with an FMV of $20/share

I found a couple of resources ([mystockoptions.com](https://www.mystockoptions.com/articles/isos-and-wash-sales-a-trap-within-a-trap) and [DRS Financial Partners](https://drsfp.com/insights/avoiding-the-iso-wash-sale-trap-and-a-big-tax-blunder)) that indicate the Nov 30th events would likely make things much worse for me since my initial exercise paper gains ($39,000) would be treated as regular income instead of being limited to the actual gains ($19,000) due to the wash sale.

**Can I simply sell both the RSUs and ESPP shares immediately to avoid being a wash sale,** or does the purchase (or vesting) act *itself* turn the Nov 15th sale into a wash sale, regardless of subsequent disposition?

Additionally, I may be able to opt out of the ESPP purchase (TBD if that's a good idea), but I don't think I can opt out of RSU vesting. **Would the RSU vesting alone trigger a wash sale for 50 shares, so 950 shares receive a disqualifying disposition and generate short-term capital gains?**

Comment: Can you reschedule when you perform each of those transactions on the same security? Just letting the wash-sale window time out is the easiest fix. (I've been doing some rebalancing recently and taking that approach. I have no reason to rush; I'm not trying to time the market.)

Comment: @keshlam, no, considering trading is restricted by open trading windows and the year is ending soon, meaning taxes (especially AMT) need to be resolved soon.